# Angular material overwrite style.css

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the `padding` on `mat-cell` and I've noticed some weird behavior.
If I write the css inside the component's css file everything works just fine, but if I write it in `style.css` (I want to apply it to the whole app) it gets overwritten by the default.

I guess this has to do with the order in which the css files are applied. If that is the case, how can I see this order and is there a way to change it or bring `style.css` on top?

Comment: Have you tried with "!important"?

Comment: "!important" fixes the problem, but that won't allow it to be further overwritten in certain components, and I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to create a separate .scss file reserved for styling globaly Angular Material elements, and importing it in the main styles.scss file.
Answering your question - propably you're not 'specific' enough. First of all it would be nice to add an additional custom class to your Material element so the custom styles will be applied only when this class is present. Example on styling

```
.mat-table.my-custom-class {
   width: 100%;

   .mat-cell {
     font-size: 20px;
     padding: 20px;
   }
}
```

You might nest the elements event more for higher css specificity

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
.mat-cell {
  padding: 12px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the parent scope of default style which is overriding css added in style.css using developer tool. Use the same parental scope along with !important.